Ubuntu 24.04 Installer crashed a lot
I decided to install Ubuntu but it kept getting crashed all the time. This has never happened before. First, it took me straight to the live usb environment instead of installer where I could choose to try or install. I don't know if they have removed this option or not. Then it crashed after updating installer.
Then while selecting additional software and drivers, it crashed. Then it crashed a lot while manual partitioning. I don't want to format my home partition on a second hard drive but I couldn't as while selecting don't format option, the installer kept crashing.
I used balena etcher to create Bootable usb of Ubuntu.
Update: I have tried creating bootable USB from Windows using Rufus as well. I have already downloaded Ubuntu 24.04 iso through torrent and direct download multiple times but still the same issue. I also verified these iso files. I heard that Kubuntu installer works fine but I wanted to have Gnome DE.
faisal6309@localhost:~/Downloaenter code hereds> gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: directory '/home/faisal6309/.gnupg' created
gpg: can't open 'SHA256SUMS.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory

faisal6309@localhost:~/Downloads> gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: Signature made Thu 25 Apr 2024 10:26:32 PM PKT
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key

faisal6309@localhost:~/Downloads> gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: /home/faisal6309/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: key 46181433FBB75451: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2

faisal6309@localhost:~/Downloads> gpg --keyid-format long --list-keys --with-fingerprint 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
pub   dsa1024/46181433FBB75451 2004-12-30 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632  CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451
uid                 [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   rsa4096/D94AA3F0EFE21092 2012-05-11 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid                 [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>


faisal6309@localhost:~/Downloads> gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: Signature made Thu 25 Apr 2024 10:26:32 PM PKT
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]

faisal6309@localhost:~/Downloads> sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso: OK


Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is available on many architectures with different installers, but you've not said what 24.04 ISO you're using. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server & Desktop use different installers for amd64 for example, so it may help if you specify which you're asking about. Did you verify ISO prior to writing to media?  Did ISO validation complete successfully (on install media; it's something I'd check!), or check ISO being written successfully prior to boot?

Did you verify the ISO that the boot media was made from? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

I did verify ISO and compared it to https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/SHA256SUMS this. It is same.

Possible duplicate of Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD
